# How to install Quercus on Linux with Tomcat 8

Tags: java, php, linux, tomcat, quercus

I have a running Tomcat server and recently wanted to get phpmyadmin used with MySQL on Linux. I have researched a bit and found that Quercus can be used for PHP on Tomcat. I then started my installation.

I have downloaded the quercus.war, put it under */tomcat/webapps/ROOT*, restarted tomcat, and tested on browser. However it's not working, index.php gives "PHP files are not being interpreted by Quercus" which I think it means failure.

I then searched and tried to put the quercus.jar (from quercus.war) under */tomcat/lib/* then restarted Tomcat. It gives the same page and same message with index.php.

EDIT:
I have tried to modify */tomcat/web.xml*, at the same time removed quercus.jar from */tomcat/lib* and restarted tomcat. This time it gives HTTP 404,requested resource is not avaliable

My questions are:

1. Is there anything I missed or is there anything wrong?
2. Further, how do I install phpmyadmin after my installation of Quercus?

Comment: I edited your question by removing the code formatting (paths isn't code). Maybe you should add the quercus tag as well?

Comment: @Magnilex Thanks,the maximum number I can tag is 5. I removed mysql tag and add quercus tag :-)

Answer (score 0):

I decided not to use phpmyadmin and switch to VDBC. I put vdbc.war under */tomcat/webapps/* and restarted tomcat, everything goes fine now.

EDIT: I tried to put quercus directory under */tomcat/webapps/* and it works! However, I still cannot figure out how to make phpmyadmin run, is there any advice?